# PowerShell Multidimensional Array-fill a variable with the value from one array based off the value of another array

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

This takes some 'splaining so stick with me.  I have an array of arrays that is used to build out a user menu that looks like this:

1. ( ) Item 1
2. ( ) Item 2
3. ( ) Item 3

Each line is an array (the outside array) and then there are three inside elements (the inside arrays) that consist of the number, the blank (actually a space character) within the bracket, and the item name (i.e. Item 1).

Via some DO/While and Switch wizardry this menu appears to be interactive; the user can toggle one or more items that they want to modify by entering in the item number.  This is done by changing the inside array that is a space character into an "X"...which is updated immediately on the screen.  So if the user wants to modify items 1 and 3 the menu will look like this:

1. (X) Item 1
2. ( ) Item 2
3. (X) Item 3

Once the user is satisfied with their selection(s) they commit their selection (exits the Do/While Loop) and the script continues to the next part (which is where I need help).

Now what I want to do is write the item name of every item that has been selected by the user into a new array (just a single array); but I can't seem to make the connection of if the outside array contains an "X" to write the 3rd inside array (within that array) to a variable.

Below is my code.  Remember $Menu is a single level array, and the "X" option for the switch is to commit the selection for the next part of the script.

```
Do {
        Clear-Host
        # Menu title
        Write-Host "Configuration Menu`n"

        # Menu items (dynamic)
        $Count=0
        ForEach($_ in $Menu){
            If($Count -le 8) {Write-Host " $($Menu[$Count][0]).  ($($Menu[$Count][1])) $($Menu[$Count][2])"}
            Else {Write-Host " $($Menu[$Count][0]). ($($Menu[$Count][1])) $($Menu[$Count][2])"}
            $Count+=1
        }

        Write-Host "`n S  - Select All"
        Write-Host " D  - Deselect All"
        Write-Host " #  - Toggles the correlating menu item"
        Write-Host " X  - Commit"
        Write-Host "[Q] - Quit"

        Write-Host "`n Select the configuration settings you want to change"
        $UserIn1=Read-Host " "

        Switch($UserIn1) {
            
            #I removed other options that aren't part of this question
            X {
                # The below lines write just the arrays with the "X" to a new array called $Selection
                # This way $Selection only has the user-selected array sets
                # But this just writes each internal array as it's own array and not as a set
                # Also, the beginning array is populated from an XML document, so the text is not
                # displayed, only the text "SystemObject[]"
                $Count=0
                ForEach($_ in $Menu){
                    $Selection+=@($Menu[$Count][2] | Where-Object {$_ -match "X"} | Out-String)
                }

                #At one point in time I think I got $Selection to get the actual arrays, but 
                #Its not currently working right.  The idea below is that once I got an array
                #of just the user selected array sets, that I could then write the Item name
                #$Config[..][2] into $ConfigureItem for each array set the user selected.
                #So $ConfigureItem would be an array of just the item names...which I need
                # to get in order for the next step to play well (and dynamicly) with my
                # xml file which the user is actually modifying.
                $Count=0
                ForEach($Item in $Selection) {
                    $ConfigureItem+=@($Selection[$Count][2])
                    $Count+=1
                }

                Clear-Host
                Write-Host "$ConfigureItem"
                Write-Host "Did the test pass?"

                pause


                Configure
                $Commit=$True
        } # End of switch
    }
    While($Commit -ne $True)
```

Comment: You should just check to see if `$UserIn1` was given a number. Then use that number to access your array index. For example, `$UserIn1 = 2; if ($UserIn1 -match '^[1-3]$') { $Menu[($UserIn1-1)][1] = '(X)' }`.

Answer (score 0):

I was waaaaaaay over-complicating things.  After a break I realized the solution was a lot simpler.  The below code solved my issues...I just needed to incorporate an If statement and not use where-object.

```
$Count=0
                ForEach($_ in $Menu){
                    If($Menu[$Count][1] -eq "X") {
                        $Selection+=@($Menu[$Count][2])
                    }
                    $Count+=1
                }
```